# File '/var/www/cms/numbers/numberswithnatinality.csv' not found (Errcode: 13)

Tags: mysql, csv, file-io

i am having cvs file name `numberswithnatinality.csv` in the path `/var/www/cms/numbers/` i am also set the file and folder permission to chmod 777 (rwxrwxrwx) but still i am getting error my query :

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/www/cms/numbers/numberswithnatinality.csv' INTO TABLE contact
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES
(
name,mobile1,nationality,twon, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy, @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy , @dummy
);
```

can you guys tell me how to fix this error, thanks

Comment: Are you *really* sure that's what the file is called? "natinality" instead of "nationality"?

Comment: i am sure the file name is natinality

Comment: And if you copy-paste `ls /var/www/cms/numbers/numberswithnatinality.csv` to a shell prompt it lists the file?

Comment: How exactly do you run that code? You type it in some MySQL client? You run it through PHP?

Comment: Do you mean the mysql command line utility? Do you run it in the local machine where the server runs or in a remote one?

Answer (score 1):

All points to a permission error:

```
$ perror 13
OS error code  13:  Permission denied
```

You need to ensure that whatever user your MySQL command prompt runs as has permission to access each intermediate directory.

Additionally, in modern OSes there're more security mechanisms than plain file attributes. For instance, it's possible that SELinux or a similar tool prevents your user from reading files at `/var/www` (which is the territory of Apache users). Since you don't probably have access to server-wide log files, you might try other locations.